# I need my API to print a list of titles as well as a full description. I am having trouble getting a list of titles. Any advice?

Tags: ruby, api

```rb
class RecipePuppyAPI1
      URL = "http://www.recipepuppy.com/api/"

    def get_recipes
     uri = URI.parse(URL)
      response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
       JSON.parse(response.body)
    end

    def recipe_titles(json)
     recipes = []
      json.collect do |recipe|
        recipes << recipe["title"]
    end
  end
end

recipes = RecipePuppyAPI1.new.get_recipes
puts ap recipes.uniq
```

Comment: hey there, maybe if you add an example of what you have inside the json, like the structure etc, and you provide a small example you will probably get an answer

Comment: Just as Code only answers are not really acceptable, Code only questions are frowned upon and usually get flagged as "Needs details or clarity"

Comment: _I am having trouble_ doesn't tell us much. What problem do you have? What is your question? Do you see an unexpected result? Is there an error, what does it say?

Comment: Your use of `collect` is missing the point: That will *collect* things into a new array, so `recipes = json.collect do |recipe|` then `recipe['title']` in the interior is all you need.

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Your `recipe_titles` method doesn't return the right thing. `collect` is used to map 1:1 an input array to an output array, and the output of each iteration is the result.

It looks like you're confusing `each`, an iterator, with `collect`, which is a *transform operation*. You're also declaring an array which isn't used properly, as normally that'd be your return value.

To fix it, remove the temporary variable, strip it down to this:

```rb
def recipe_titles(json)
  json.collect do |recipe|
    recipe["title"]
  end
end
```

Or more generically:

```rb
def recipe_fields(json, field)
  json.collect do |recipe|
    recipe[field]
  end
end
```

Where you can call it like:

```rb
recipe_fields(json, 'title')
```